# SQSListener missing message Id

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have an SQSListener setup, Although its receiving the payload, It is missing the messageId for the consumed message, is there anything I am doing wrong?, 
Below is my code,

```
@SqsListener(value = "${test-queue-url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
  public void listen(Acknowledgment acknowledgment, String message, String messageId) {
    // messageId == null here 
    LOG.info(messageId);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed my code to and extracted the value from headers

```
@Async
  @SqsListener(value = "${queue-url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
  public void listen(Acknowledgment acknowledgment, String message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String messageId = (String) headers.get("MessageId");
    acknowledgment.acknowledge().get();
  }
```